# sympy error 'Symbol' object is not callable

Tags: python, symbols, sympy, solver

I am trying to solve an equation for r when given values for x and y. to do this I am using the solve ability of sympy. the code that I have is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import acos,sin

x=2
y=-2
r=Symbol("r",real=True)
solve(r(acos(1.0-(y/r)))-sin(acos(1.0-(y/r)))-x)
```

when I run the code it gives me the error

```
'Symbol' object is not callable
line 10, in <module>
    solve(r(acos(1.0-(y/r)))-sin(acos(1.0-(y/r)))-x)
```

the reason I import numpy and matplotlib is that I will use them later in my code. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to multiply r with the part in parentheses, write r*(...)

Comment: @Michael have you tried your suggestion?

Comment: @NicolasGervais No, to be honest. Of course the parentheses around the first "acos(...)" expression could then also be omitted but I don't see that this would make a difference.

Comment: It doesn't run for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error directs you toward what to look for: a Symbol that is being called. In Python syntax this is a Symbol followed by pair of parentheses with one or more arguments between them. You probably intended to multiply by `r` in the first argument of the expression:

```
>>> solve(r(acos(1.0-(y/r)))...
           ^__make that r*acos(1.0-(y/r))...
```

An editor that highlights matching parentheses (like the online editor of Python code at repl.it) can be helpful in these circumstances. Parentheses are either grouping or, when following a Python name, acting as the delimiters for the arguments being passed to a function.